# Create custom collection view delegate/data source

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have a controller called **MyController**, which is **UIViewController**. Inside of the controller there's CollectionView. Let's call it **myCollectionView**. How would I create custom CollectionViewDelegate or DataSource such that I could use them for **myCollectionView**. I've already attempted to create custom delegate and data source but my collection view is just empty. I found that actually my custom delegate and data source's methods do not even get called which is why I basically see an empty collection view. What I've tried is:

```
final class MyController: UIViewController {
  private lazy var collectionView = methodCreatesCollectionView()

  private var items: [String]?
  private var customDataSource: CustomDataSource?

  init() {
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    view.addSubview(collectionView)

    customDataSource = CustomDataSource(parent: self)
    collectionView.reloadData()
  }

  func fill(with items: [String]) {
    self.items = items
  }

  func methodCreatesCollectionView() -> UICollectionView {
    let cv = UICollectionView(
      frame: self.view.bounds
    )
    cv.dataSource = customDataSource
    return cv
  }
}
```

#### What my custom data source looks like

```
private class CustomDataSource: NSObject, UICollectionViewDataSource {
  weak var parent: MyController?

  init(parent: MyController) {
    self.parent = parent
  }

  func collectionView(
    _: UICollectionView,
    numberOfItemsInSection section: Int
  ) -> Int {
    guard let numberOfItems = parent?.items?.count else {
      return 0
    }
    return numberOfItems
  }

  func numberOfSections(
    in _: UICollectionView
  ) -> Int {
    return 1
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I found my own mistake.

If anyone else is doing it like me, remember to call everything related to collection view before it gets called first time.

So you have to initialise your data source/delegate before you add the collection view into the view hierarchy because the way it gets created is **lazy**. So it'll be created only when it's accessed/called first time.